# How to fit (or scale) a vector image to the phone/emulator screen width (and height, if needed)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get the effect of the image on the left (shows well in android preview) but i'm getting the effect of the image on the right (emulator).

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun Login(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    Box {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_login_bg),
            contentDescription = "background"
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.welcomeback),
            modifier = Modifier
                .paddingFromBaseline(top = 152.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}

@Preview("Login Light Theme", widthDp = 360, heightDp = 640)
@Composable
fun LoginLightPreview() {
    WeTradeTheme {
        Surface(color = Color.White) {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            Login(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

The vector image is:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="360dp"
    android:height="319dp"
    android:viewportWidth="360"
    android:viewportHeight="319">
  <group>
    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h360v319h-360z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M485.322,293.22C426.908,276.133 412,319 300.942,319C189.885,319 154,259 16.273,294.895C-20.04,309.74 -56.548,331.258 -84.365,359.728C-106.048,381.92 -136.223,413.966 -149.027,442.237C-158.266,462.636 -199.615,488.882 -170.539,505.122C-172.334,512.031 -206.906,522.916 -208.062,530.146L-208.049,530.933C-208.101,530.676 -208.104,530.414 -208.062,530.146L-209.238,454.91L-396.461,-526.739L300.942,-673.524L485.322,293.22Z">
      <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient 
            android:startY="423.834"
            android:startX="-26.5365"
            android:endY="-531.219"
            android:endX="400.917"
            android:type="linear">
          <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF322049"/>
          <item android:offset="0.938994" android:color="#FF374092"/>
        </gradient>
      </aapt:attr>
    </path>
  </group>
</vector>
```

Here is a few things i tried already:

- Use Modifier.scale(1.10f) in the image. Of course this works but its not scalable since different screens have different sizes and so the scaling factor is also different.
- Use BoxWithConstraints: same effect as if use Box.

Anyone knows how this can be done using compose?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a modifier on the Box and/or Image with `fillMaxWidth()`?

Comment: I have, no effect. And that result i can understand, because image shows already with full width and height. I mean, as i understand max width regarding the image, not the device/emulator.

Comment: `fillMaxWidth()` on the image, center the image (still on the top). Humm. interesting behaviour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector has `android:width="360dp"` and your Preview has the same width: `widthDp = 360`. It is the reason because in the first image you don't have the white space on the right edge.

You can apply `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` to your Image to fill the `Box` width, and then you have to set the appropriate [**`ContentScale`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/ContentScale) (for example **`Crop`**, but it depends by what you want to achieve):

```
 Box(){
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.vector),
        contentDescription = "background",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )
    //...
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Must be used `fillMaxWidth()` AND `ContentScale.Crop`, they probably work in tandem. One OR other don't work. Thanks!

Comment: From the `ContentScale.Crop` documentation, it scales the source to be as large as the destination. My common sense would say that's a task of a FIT function. Just saying...